# Installing Local Gem Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

All right so I have a gem file the is local. In my rails application the gem spec file and the created gem along with all files bundled is located at:

```
vendor/gems/mygem
```

In my Gemfile I have

```
gem 'mygem-1.0', :path => 'vendor/gems/mygem'
```

When I run:

```
bundle install
```

I get an error:

```
Could not find gem 'mygem-1.0 x86-mingw32' in source at 'vendor/gems/mygem' in source at 'vendor/gems/mygem/'.
Source does not contain any version of 'mygem-1.0 x86-mingw32'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after taking a break for a few minutes. I noticed that I was actually calling the version number of the gem as part of the gem name:

```
# What I originally Had
gem 'mygem-1.0', :path 'vendor/gems/mygem'

# What it should be
gem 'mygem', :path 'vendor/gems/mygem'
```

the bundler added the version number to the gem automatically and I assumed this was part of the file name and the version was specified inside the gemfile itself.